# How do I pass a class attribute via a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `PostsHelper`, that helps me generate links:

```
module PostsHelper
  def populate_update_link(link1, link2, parameter)
    if current_user
      public_send(link2, parameter)
    else
      public_send(link1)
    end
  end
end
```

I call it like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Update', populate_update_link('new_post_path', 'new_post_path', parent_id: @post) %>
```

What I would like to generate is a link like this though:

```
<%= link_to "(Update)", "#", class: "togglesidebar" %>
```

How do I send a class via `public_send` to the generated link?

Comment: What class attribute? From what class? It's not clear what you mean here. Helper methods generally need to have everything as arguments for maximum clarity.

Comment: I believe he wants to send to `class: "string generated here from method"` - problem is that it isn't clear what method would determine the string output `togglesidebar`. Also, I'm curious what the motivation for using `public_send` when you're not invoking any method types into the argument?

Comment: @tadman What Besto said. I want to send a css class with the link. Not a Ruby class. Besto, what other way is there for me to do this without using `public_send`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the rails API, you can setup html options for a given link on the third parameter of link_to (ie http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

In your case you would need to define another method which return an array of options such as {id: "my_id", class: "my_class_1 my_class_2"} and call this method as the 3rd parameter of link_to.

```
def generate_html_options(param_1, param_2)
....
body
....
return hash of options
end
```

Intended to be use like this:

```
<%= link_to('Update', populate_update_link('new_post_path', 'new_post_path', parent_id: @post), generate_html_options(...)) %>
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to approach it. Thanks!

Comment: That should be "hash of options" as an array would necessarily need to be splatted to use like that.